# How to change bg color of standard tile in tile container based on property from json

Tags: sapui5

I try to dynamically change background color of every tile with some property (in json file I have property in different tiles like `"tileColorGroup": "Group1", "tileColorGroup": "Group2", "tileColorGroup": "Group3"`...and so on  every group have own background color.

I'm using XML views and JS controllers. I tried to achieve that by code below in my `view1.controller.js`

```
onInit : function () {          
  var oTileContainer = this.byId("TileContainer");    
  var oTiles = oTileContainer.getTile();
  console.log("oTiles: " + oTiles); <--- no value
```

Maybe exists better way to do it?

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `TileContainer` control only then you can achieve it by using formatter and CSS.

VIEW

```
<TileContainer
    id="container"
    class="tileContainerHolder"
    tiles="{/TileCollection}">
    <StandardTile
        icon="{icon}"
        type="{type}"
        number="{number}"
        numberUnit="{numberUnit}"
        title="{parts: [ 'title', 'tileColorGroup'], formatter:'my.Formatter.addBackgroundColor'}"
        info="{info}"
        infoState="{infoState}" />
</TileContainer>
```

Formatter.js

```
jQuery.sap.declare("my.Formatter");
my.Formatter = {
    addBackgroundColor: function (title, tileColorGroup) {
        this.addStyleClass("grp" + tileColorGroup);//Add group class
        return title;
    }
};
```

CSS

```
.tileContainerHolder .grpGroup1.sapMTile {
    background: #f0ab00;
}
.tileContainerHolder .grpGroup2.sapMTile {
    background: #007cc0;
}
.tileContainerHolder .grpGroup3.sapMTile {
    background: #008a3b;
}
```

> Note: For adding the class you need to use any one of the bind
>   property like title here so that we can get the instance of the Tile
>   and add the corresponding class to it.

Answer (score 2):

`TileContainer` does not have a method `getTile` - the method is `getTiles`. That may be why your code is not working.

Also note that `TileContainer` is deprecated in SAPUI5 1.50.

You could extend the `GenericTile` control to provide a property for background colour that you can bind to.